# comparison two arrays in JS in linear time complexities

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity

I had such a recruitment task to do.

> Write a function that receives two arrays: ArrayA and ArrayB of integers sequences and returns Array3. ArrayC should contains all elements from ArrayA (maintaining the order) except those, that are present in ArrayB p times, where p is a prime number.
> Example:
>
> - ArrayA: `[3,4,10,3,6,2,4,8,11]`
> - ArrayB: `[3,2,4,5,4,11,7,7,2,8,11,11,11]`
> - ArrayC: `[3,10,3,6,8,11]`
>
> *Notes: Write an algorithm with good time complexity*

Below I insert my solution.
I received the feedback that linear time complexities was expected.

I wondering if it is possible to get O(n) time complexity in JS when we compare two arrays. I think that in this case iteration through two arrays is necessary, so we have O(n^2), right?

If O(n) is possible I will be gratefull for the solution. I hope I learn something

```
const countInArray = (arr, value) =>
  arr.filter((item) => item === value).length;

const isPrime = (value) => {
  if (value === 1) return false;
  for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(value); i++) {
    if (value % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const pushToNewArr = (seq1, seq2, returnedSeq) => {
  seq1.map((number) => {
    const occurNumber = countInArray(seq2, number);
    if (!occurNumber) {
      return returnedSeq.push(number);
    } else {
      if (!isPrime(occurNumber)) {
        return returnedSeq.push(number);
      } else return false;
    }
  });
};

const returnNewSequence = (seq1, seq2, returnedSeq) =>
  pushToNewArr(seq1, seq2, returnedSeq);

const ArrayA=[3,4,10,3,6,2,4,8,11]
const ArrayB=[3,2,4,5,4,11,7,7,2,8,11,11,11]
const ArrayC = [];

returnNewSequence(ArrayA, ArrayB, ArrayC);
```

Comment: use `Set` which can be done in `O(n)`

Comment: "good time complexity" doesn't necessarily mean "linear time complexity"

Comment: You defined `n` to be the prime number. In that case `O(n)` is clearly not possible. That would mean it would be independent of the sizes of the two arrays. If you don't mean that, use a different name for the prime number and specify precisely what you mean by `n` in "`O(n)`".

Comment: Also, you stated the question in such a way that `n` is a fixed given prime number. Your code suggests otherwise, so please fix the question accordingly.

Comment: @Barmar, the company I applied for gave me a feedback, that they expected the "linear time complexity"

Answer (score 0):

```
seq1.map((number) => {
    const occurNumber = countInArray(seq2, number);
    (...)
}
```

This part leads to `O(n^2)` complexity, because for each element in the first array, you're iterating over the second array. To fix this, iterate through the second array, count the elements, check for primes and store the numbers to exclude. Then iterate over the first array, removing the numbers as needed. This results to `O(n)` time (which is the same as `O(2n)` when dealing with asymptotes).

However, this needs to be multiplied by the time complexity of the primality testing. That's a completely different and very complex topic, especially if you want to do it optimally. From a quick glance, your function runs in `O(sqrt(n))` time, resulting in `O(n * sqrt(n))` time total. For practical purposes, you could get away by just storing a (sufficiently large) list of primes in a map for `O(1)` complexity for checking if a number is a prime or not.

Comment: Memoize `isPrime()` and use Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 0):

```
const isPrime = (value) => {
  if (value === 1) return false;
  for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(value); i++) {
    if (value % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const getNewSequence = (ArrayA, ArrayB) => {
  const countInB = ArrayB.reduce(
    (counts, num) => Object.assign(counts, { [num]: 1 + (counts[num] || 0) }),
    {}
  );

  const set = new Set();

  return ArrayA.reduce((seq, num) => {
    const occurNumber = countInB[num];
    if (!occurNumber || set.has(num) || !isPrime(occurNumber)) {
      seq.push(num);
      set.add(num);
    }

    return seq;
  }, []);
};

const ArrayA = [3, 4, 10, 3, 6, 2, 4, 8, 11];
const ArrayB = [3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 11, 7, 7, 2, 8, 11, 11, 11];
const ArrayC = getNewSequence(ArrayA, ArrayB);
```

Now we don't iterate each time the second array to get the count and also we have a set to keep track if we have already added the number so we don't have to use isPrime as much. But there is an extra check with set.has(). It can be optimized better, but this should be faster now.

Comment: This is not `O(n)`, however, because of `isPrime`.

Comment: @AngelZlatanov, are you able to explain step by step how this function works?
I mean why it returns: { 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 7: 2, 8: 1, 11: 4 } 

`const countInB = ArrayB.reduce(
    (counts, num) => Object.assign(counts, { [num]: 1 + (counts[num] || 0) }),
    {}
  );`

Comment: Basically like:
let countInB = {};
ArrayB.forEach((num) => (countInB[num] = 1 + (countInB[num] || 0)));
Does it make more sense now?
We are making an object (key:value pair) containing the count for each number in the second array. { key: value } -> { number: count }

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. I was a little confused why COUNTS from reduce fn was set as a target in Object.assign. When I printed COUNTS in the console i got something like that: 3, {}, {}, {}

Comment: As Mo B suggested you must optimize the prime number check. But I don't think if generating prime numbers in range is a good idea. Maybe if you make a function which saves the currently generated prime numbers in it's context and return another function which returns values from the already generated ones and generate new ones only when needed it would be perfect. I hope I make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your main question is whether it's possible to solve the problem in `O(n)`.

First of all, let's assume by `n` you mean the combined length `n = a + b` of both input arrays.

Whether it's possible in `O(n)` or not depends on what you exactly mean. I strongly believe it's not possible in `O(n)` *worst-case*, but *proving* that will be very difficult. It's certainly possible in `O(n log n)` *worst-case* and `O(n)` on average. Like so:

1. Generate the first `b` prime numbers. Don't use the Sieve of Erathosthenes since it is `O(b log(log(b)))` which is *almost* linear but not quite. Use the Sieve of Atkin instead, which is `O(b)`.
2. Memoize the prime numbers in a sparse boolean array of size `b`, so checking if a number (up to `b`) is prime can be done in `O(1)`.
3. Iterate through `ArrayB` while counting the occurrences of the items, thereby creating an associative map from items to their counts. If you use a hash table, this can be done in `O(b)` *on average*, but `O(b^2)` worst-case. If you use a self-balancing binary search tree, this can be done in `O(b log(b))`.
4. Iterate through `ArrayA` and take the elements that satisfy your condition. Using the constructed maps from Steps 2 and 3, that is done in `O(a)` on average if you used a hash table in Step 3 and `O(ab)` worst-case. If you used a self-balancing tree, this will be `O(a log(b))`.

So (using `n=a + b`) using a hash table in Step 3 will give you `O(n)` in total on average, but `O(n^2)` worst-case. Using a self-balancing search tree gives you `O(n log n)` worst-case.